# Why is this string always the highest possible number

Tags: python

```
if month == 1 or 10:
    month1 = 0
if month == 2 or 3 or 11:
    month1 = 3
if month == 4 or 7:
    month1 = 6
if month == 5:
    month1 = 1
if month == 6:
    month1 = 4
if month == 8:
    month1 = 2
if month == 9 or 12:
    month1 = 5
```

This code *always* returns `month1` equal to `5`. I'm quite new at programming, what am I doing wrong? (I guess it involves the fact that 12 is the highest number, but `==` means equals right?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: I first gave the wrong reason why this is not working.  As others have pointed out,

```
if month == 1 or 10:
    # ...
```

is equivalent to

```
if (month == 1) or 10:
    # ...
```

So `...` always gets executed.

You could use

```
if month in (1, 10):
    month1 = 0
```

or even better

```
a = [0, 3, 3, 6, 1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5]
month1 = a[month - 1]
```

or

```
d = {1: 0, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 6, 5: 1, 6: 4,
     7: 6, 8: 2, 9: 5, 10: 0, 11: 3, 12: 5}
month1 = d[month]
```

instead.

Yet another way of getting the same result would be to use the `datetime` module:

```
from datetime import datetime
month1 = (datetime(2011, month, 1) - datetime(2011, 1, 1)).days % 7
```

Comment: doesn't `1 or 10` evaluate to `1` since `1` evaluates to True? I was going to re-answer, but I figured an edit here would serve the purpose. I tested the above in a shell also, I'm fairly confident but don't want to change your answer just incase.

Comment: Actually, I think you've got the precedence wrong: `month == 1 or 10` will never come out False, because even if month is not 1, 10 is truthy. Toy example: `"A" == "A" or "C"` yields True, `"A" == "B" or "C"` yields "C"

Comment: @Ulrich: You are also right.  Well, probably not my best day today :)

Comment: Don't worry, that happens. :)

Answer (score 5):

When you write:

```
if month == 9 or 12:
    month1 = 5
```

it actually means:

```
if (month == 9) or (12):
    month1 = 5
```

what you want to have is:

```
if (month == 9) or (month == 12):
    month1 = 5
```

Comment: Yes. An simple answer that *answers* the problem primary without [first] delving into "more pythonic approaches".

Comment: +1 for correctly explaining why it does not work.

Comment: +1 for simply fixing the original code without refactoring!

Answer (score 1):

Also, I think you want `elif` instead of just `if`:

```
if month == 1 or month == 10:
    month1 = 0
elif month == 2 or month == 3 or month == 11:
    month1 = 3
elif month == 4 or month == 7:
    month1 = 6
elif month == 5:
    month1 = 1
elif month == 6:
    month1 = 4
elif month == 8:
    month1 = 2
elif month == 9 or month == 12:
    month1 = 5
```

If the first condition (month is 1 or 10) is true, it will jump over the others.

Comment: While you're at it, you might as well fix up lines 5 and 13...

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what's being asked, but I'd suggest re-implementing  that using a dict as a quick lookup table. Eg:

```
month_lut = {
    1  : 0,
    10 : 0,
    2  : 3,
    3  : 3,
   11  : 3,
    4  : 6, 
    7  : 6,
    # more ...
}

month1 = month_lut[month]
```

Not only does it look more intuitive (to me anyway), you get a `KeyError` exception (which can be handled properly) if `month` is invalid instead of failing silently and ending up with an undefined `month1`.

Comment: I explained the problem in this way, but I was wrong.  Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: @Sven. True.. retracting my statement.

Comment: +1 for most elegant solution. Although others are more explanatory, this shows a good straightforward approach to the problem (if we assume there isn't a rule for the corresponding numbers, as it seems).

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You are using independent ifs (if, if, if), so every one of them will be tried every time. If you used cascading ifs (if, elif, elif), you would always get back month1=0 because:
2. Your comparisons are not what you think!  'month == 1 or 10' will always return either True or 10. if month is 1, then month==1 is True, then True or 10 is True, and the body of the if statement gets run. In every other case, month==1 is False, and False or 10 is 10, which is 'truthy', so the if statement gets run!

Answer (score 0):

A note on how the python `or` operator works:

For an expression `x or y`:

In the case that `x` is `True`, the expression returns `x`. This makes intuitive sense when x is a boolean--if `x` is `True` it returns `True`. In the case that `x` is `False`, then `y` is returned. This makes intuitive sense when `y` is a boolean. If `x` is `False` and `y` is `True`, you get a value of `True` from your `or` expression.

However, things get trickier when either `x` is not a boolean, or x is `False` and `y` is not a boolean. In your case, `month == 1` is a boolean. As in the rules above, when this is false, it returns the second half of the `or` expression. Since `10` is not a boolean, but an integer, it is simply returned.

The reason `month1` always equals 5 is that in your last two lines you have such a problem. In your statement

```
if month == 9 or 12:
```

python first checks to see what the or statement returns. Here, it will either return `True` (if the month actually is 9) or if month is not nine, since 12 isn't a boolean, it will return 12. Both of these values (`True` and `12) cause the if statement to pass, and the line after it to be evaluated, setting month1 to 12.s

I would note that the other answers explain better approaches to this code. However, it is still useful to understand how Boolean Operators work in python.